# How to print specific lines of a file in Python

Tags: python

I have a `.txt` file and I would like to print lines `3, 7, 11, 15,...`

So, after printing the third line, I would like to print every 4th line afterward.

I began by looking at the modulus operator:

```
#Open the file
with open('file.txt') as file:

  #Iterate through lines
  for i, line in enumerate(file):

      #Choose every third line in a file
      if i % 3 == 0:
          print(line)

  #Close the file when you're done
  file.close()
```

but that approach prints every third line. If `i % 3 == 1` that prints lines 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 etc.

Comment: I'm gonna make a comment instead of an answer. I've tried out all of the solutions and they all work, so I don't know who deserves the best answer here. I would like to thank Kingsley, Moberg and Sayse for their answers.

Comment: Edit: many others commented as well, so I will choose the first on the list as the best answer. Thank you, everyone, for helping me out on here. Much appreciated!

Comment: Remember that you don't have to remember to close your file when you use with.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the documentation afterward and it says exactly this. My take from this is to read the documentation more carefully. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using modulo, simply just use addition, start it with the first line you want to show, and then add 4 to it

```
next_line = 2  # Line 3 is index 2
for i, line in enumerate(file):

    if i == next_line:
        print(line)
        next_line = next_line + 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost fine, except for the modulo: you want the remainder of the division by 4 to be 3.

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
  for i, line in enumerate(file):
      if i % 4 == 3:
          print(line)
```

Note that you don't need to explicitely `close` your file at the end: that's what `with` is intended for, it makes sure that your file gets closed whatever happens.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to something to happen every fourth time, that means modulo 4. Try changing your if to `if i % 4 == N:` with a good number for `N`.

By  the way, when using the `with` statement you have don't have to call `close()`, it does so automatically.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
# Fetch all lines from the file
lines = open('20 - Modular OS - lang_en_vs2.srt').readlines()

# Print the 3rd line
print(lines[2])

# throw away the first 3 lines, so the modulo (below) works ok
for i in range(3):
    del(lines[0])

# print every 4th line after that
for (i in range(len(lines)):
    if (i > 0 and i % 4 == 0):
        print(lines[i])
```

Read every line into an array.
Output the 3rd line.
We then need every fourth line, so by deleteing the first 3 elements, it's easy to simply test against modulo 4 (the "% 4") and output the line.

Comment: Should it be `del(lines[i])`?

Comment: @Sigur - No, `lines[0]` is always the first line in the list, as each is deleted, the *next* line becomes `lines[0]`.  So for 3 times, the code removes the first line.

Comment: Oh, now I see... smart.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
with open('file.txt') as file:

  #Iterate through lines
  for i, line in enumerate(file):
      x += 1
      #Choose every third line in a file
      if x == 4:
          print(line)
          x = 0

  #Close the file when you're done
  file.close()
```

### Result

```
>>> i = 0
>>> for x in range(0, 100):
...     i += 1
...     if i is 4:
...         print(x)
...         i = 0
```

3
7
11
15
19
23
27
31
35
39
43
47
51
55
59
63
67
71
75
79
83
87
91
95
99

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('file.txt')
print(file[2])
#Iterate through lines
for i in file:
  #Choose every third line in a file, beginning with 4
  if i % 4 == 0:
      print(i+3)
  elif i % 4 == 0:
      print(i)
```

This works, but isn't super elegant.